# How to slice categorical data

Tags: python

I have a dataset which is a football players details. This is how the dtypes are:

```
Name                   object
Age                     int64
Nationality            object
Overall                 int64
Club                   object
Potential               int64
Preferred Positions    object
Rem Potential           int64
dtype: object
```

Now suppose I want to get the players who all come from a specific nationality like 'England' how do I do that?

Comment: Could you be more specific. Dataset ? Is it in Memory, Pandas, Django ORM. This would be of great help

Answer (score 1):

If the dataframe variable is df, then one way to do it is:

```
new_df = df[df['Nationality'] == 'Englad']
```